# How to bind OnClick function to list of images in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using following code to crete images programatically (dynamically in for loop):

```
function showImage(source, id) {
var list = document.getElementById("display-list");

//Image
var cellImage = document.createElement("td");
var objImage = document.createElement("img");
objImage.classList.add("obj");
cellImage.setAttribute("align", "center");
cellImage.setAttribute("valign", "bottom");
cellImage.appendChild(objImage);
list.appendChild(cellImage);

//Checkbox
var cellCheckbox = document.createElement("td");
var objCheckbox = document.createElement("input");
objCheckbox.id = id;
objCheckbox.type = 'checkbox';
cellCheckbox.setAttribute("valign", "bottom");
cellCheckbox.appendChild(objCheckbox);
list.appendChild(cellCheckbox);

objImage.src = source;
}
```

Now, I need to bind a function On Click of each image passing each image id to that function. How can I do this in JScript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'd just (a) attach the id to the image itself and (b) extract this id inside the onclick handler.

Perhaps something a little like this:

**Code edit:**

```
var objImage = document.createElement('img');
objImage.setAttribute('myId', id);
```

**Code addition:**

```
function myClickHandler(e)
{
  var clickedImage = this;
  var clickedImageId = this.getAttribute('myId');
  //
  // do something here with the image &/or id
}
```

I haven't used the .id attribute of the images, since you haven't set them yourself. You have however used the `.id` attribute of the checkbox. You can't have duplicate IDs on a page, so simply setting the `.id` of objImage to the same value as the `.id` of `objCheckbox` won't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I would say adding this should work:

```
objImage.addEventListener('click', function() {
   alert(this.id);
}, false);
```

Comment: this prints empty id for each image. Please help to resolve :(

Comment: because you are not setting id on the image